# What is the correct way to deploy EAR on Weblogic with Docker

Tags: java, docker, deployment, weblogic, containers

Docker is convenient to run fat jars, with embedded server. Just add the jar, expose the ports and run it.

But how docker fits with the traditional way of deploying EAR to weblogic server? Is docker still a viable tool for this kind of traditional packaging? Is there some well proven pattern, how to use docker for traditional style of java deployments with heavy emphasis on weblogic configuration? All the tutorials I find considers either executable jars or python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The WebLogic team seems to think so.  The WebLogic team has developed several tools in this space:

- WebLogic Deploy Tooling allows you to create WebLogic Server configurations using a metadata model in YAML - https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-deploy-tooling
- WebLogic Image Tool helps you to create a Docker image using the WebLogic version and patches of your choosing, and will use the WebLogic Deploy Tooling to create a domain in the Docker image, also.  https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-image-tool
- WebLogic Kubernetes Operator can be used to run Docker containers with WebLogic domains in a Kubernetes environment. https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-kubernetes-operator